# How do you give a User multiple users tokens in Plaid?

Tags: plaid

For my web app I am trying to allow the user to add multiple payment methods. I am using the user token in order to gain access to the income feature. However, there appears to be no way to allow multiple payment methods because the user token only corresponds to the data most recently entered through Plaid Link and trying to create a second user token fails because you cannot have repeat client user ids. How exactly do you get around this?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "user token only corresponds to the data most recently entered through Plaid Link" -- the user token doesn't contain information about a user's payment methods. What's stopping you from just sending the user through Link multiple times? You don't even need to provide a user token after the first Link, since the subsequent Link instances would only need to use the Auth product, not the Income Verification one.

Comment: I tried putting the user back through Link by just using auth, but it doesn't request bank income that way so it doesn't add that income

Comment: Is there a reason you can't save the bank income data from the user's previous Link session rather than needing to fresh bank income data every time they add a payment method?